# Automapper ForMember MapFrom doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public class Source
{
    public SourceId Identification { get; }
}

public class SourceId 
{
    public string Id { get; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Identification { get; set; }
}

public class SourceProfile : Profile
{
    public SourceProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(dest => dest.Identification, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Identification.Id));
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------

// On startup of the application

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<SourceProfile>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

---------------------------------------------------------------------

// The mapper is injected into the class where the following code is used
var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source);
var destId = dest.Identification;
```

The value of destId is "Source.SourceId". Basically the ToString() representation of the SourceId object. The mapper is not taking into account the individual member mapping for some reason.

Comment: You didn't mention how do you create mapper. I think that's the point, because it seems like default AM behaviour without your mapping settings involved.

Comment: @Leff Edited my question to show the profile and the configuration.

Comment: Anyway there's no info about where does the `mapper` come from. Does it come from a DI container or created somehow?

Comment: Yes, it's injected. Edited further

Comment: So, where's the DI registration code though?

Comment: @Leff That's not relevant since I'm sure it is being injected correctly and other simpler mappings work just fine.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure the mapping profile itself is fine, but how can I be confident it actually used in the created IMapper?

Comment: @Leff I managed to find another way, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up removing the custom member mapping and added an explicit map from the source complex type to string.

```
// old
CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(dest => dest.Identification, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Identification.Id));

// new
CreateMap<SourceId, string>().ConvertUsing(source => source.Id);
CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

I am not sure what was missing in my initial try but this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In your startup, you will need to register the profile itself, I recommend that you register the Startup class so it will find all that derive from Profile in your entire project, like this:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

Then you don't need the mapper configuration. Unless you have niche scenario where it's required.

Just on an additional info part, you can also call the mapper like this:

```
mapper.Map<Destination>(source)
```

As it will pick up the type of your source (unless you have polymorphism so your type is different).

Comment: @Ray you're very welcome, it helps so much when you add new profiles regularly and then you don't have to worry about remembering to register them!